# Compatibility with macOS Big Sur (macOS 11)

Tags: osx, compatibility

is there any experience, if the upcoming macOS Big Sur is compatible with the latest stable Blender version? I tried it in Parallels, and it keeps crashing.

Falk

Comment: It seems Apple don't care about 3d artists anymore: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198656/blender-2-9-does-not-recognize-my-gpu/198660#198660

Comment: As far as I'm aware Blender developers have received a DevKit and Apple announced that they would contribute patches, but I'm not sure how far the progress is. The development appears to happen in the [`mac_arm64` branch](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/history/mac_arm64/). You would have to compile Blender yourself since the current macOS builds aren't made for the ARM processors. It's better to ask development questions on [devtalk.blender.org](https://devtalk.blender.org/) where the developers involved in this particular area are more likely to see and answer this question.

Comment: Dear Robert, thanks a lot for the reply. I'll check that. Falk

Comment: Anyone tried this now that it's officially released?

Comment: @RobertGützkow during the launch event apple noted that they would include a new translation software called Rosetta 2 inside Big Sur which automatically translates x86 applications to be usable on ARM.

Comment: @EricXue As far as I'm aware it is intended that Blender will be compiled for ARM, hence the branch linked above. Since I'm not working on Apple hardware, I'm not in the loop with the current development in this area though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Blender 2.90.1 on MacBook Pro 2013 Retina with the latest macOS Big Sur. No issue so far. Would love for Blender to support Metal though. Fingers crossed.