# Cloth brush not working in Blender 2.91 on Macbook pro

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am having a problem with the cloth brush in the sculpting tab. I am using an M1 Macbook pro with blender 2.91.

I have laid out a plane mesh and subdivided it in the layout window, when I go to the sculpt window and try the cloth brush, nothing happens and I see two red circles on my curser that do not move away from the place I originally clicked on.

Any help? Are there settings I am unaware of?

Comment: Hi and welcome! I'd suggest try to file a bug report *(Main menu > Help > Report a Bug)*, download an older version of blender, or/and try any linux distro which should work fine... Apple dropped opengl support in favor of their new metal api, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198734/compatibility-with-macos-big-sur-macos-11#comment332756_198734

Comment: have you tried with a large radius?